# How to get output of Snowflake SQL (not javascript) stored procedure called from task

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am calling a Snowflake SQL (language SQL) stored procedure from a Snowflake task.  This is not a JAVASCRIPT stored procedure.  The stored procedure returns a value with some logging information that I would like to be able to see rather than only seeing the job was successful.  How can I see that output from the stored procedure when I look at the history of the Snowflake task?

Comment: Use - select * from table(result_scan('query_id retrieved from task_history')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an example here, for reference -

Check task status -

```
select query_id,name,state from table(information_schema.task_history());
```

| QUERY_ID | NAME | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | T1 | SCHEDULED |

Once task is executed query_id will get populated -

Use that query id to fetch result -

```
select query_id,name,state,query_text from table(information_schema.task_history());
```

| QUERY_ID | NAME | STATE | QUERY_TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | T1 | SCHEDULED | call dummy_proc() |
| 01a4af4f-3200-609f-0000-0000a9451151 | T1 | SUCCEEDED | call dummy_proc() |

```
select * from table(result_scan('01a4af4f-3200-609f-0000-0000a9451151'));
```

| DUMMY_PROC |
| --- |
| some text |